# Multiple countdown timers with dates from database jQuery/Ajax/PHP

Tags: jquery, countdown

I am trying to build deals aggregator which will load deals by AJAX, but the problem for me is to do multiple countdown timers (one for each deal) with dates from MySQL. I was trying to do something like code below but this doesn't work. Can someone give me the best solution to do it, please?

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
url:"getdata.php",
type:"GET",
dataType:'json',
success:function(rows){

for (var i in rows){
var row=rows[i];
var id=row[0];
var end_date=row[1];
$("#countdown_"+id).countdown({
            date: end_date,
            format: "on"
        },

        function() {
        // callback function
        });
}
}
});
});
```

PHP code:

```
$data=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $data[]=$row;
}
die (json_encode($data));
```

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean?  Not very informative, especially considering you have code have running on two environments and AJAX talking between the two

Comment: when I am using this code, the only last timer is counting down, the others are getting dates but are not counting down, just showing the same value all the time

Comment: there are numerous timer plugins.. which are you using?

Comment: I was trying to use this one http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/adding-a-jquery-countdown-plugin-to-our-coming-soon-page/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin was written with some global variables that wouldn't allow for multiple instances.

I made a few adjustments that made it work

See Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/afRVm/1

`.`